# Получить данные из AD

Tags: php, ldap

Доброго времени суток! не могу разобраться с функцией ldap_search() - что мне надо прописать во втором параметре? что такое base_dn?

Answer (score 1):

[Read this](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.ldap.php)
f..g [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ldap-search.php)